# Embed one silverlight application into a Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, silverlight

Embed one silverlight application into a Windows Forms Application

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Not sure if you can do this but Silverlight out-of-browser (in Silverlight 3.0) might be useful to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/katriend/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-applications.aspx. It lets you run a Silverlight application as though it were a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably embed it using a WebBrowser control although I'm sure this is not what you're after. There is no way to embed it natively since it requires a browser host.